# Pass some value from service/DAO layer to controller or Filters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am dealing with a normal web service setup, using spring. 
The scenario is: we log the `API` calls in the Filters and also do `AUDIT` logs for some Entities (Entities in this case will be Customer Clients)
So if a `POST` request is made the filters will log the `API` log in say `API_LOG` table and when the request hits the controller and down the layers to service and `DAO` the ENTITY, i.e `COSTUMER` is also logged in `AUDIT_TABLE` with info specific to changes in customer. Both logs (`API` and `AUDIT`) gets their own Id in the DB table. I have been tasked to link both the tables i.e when `API` call is logged it should have the `AUDIT` id added to it. 
The problem I am facing it how to pass the `auditId` created for that specific `API` `POST` call to the filters. Since the `API` log has the response also logged to it, the audit log happens first and then the api log is recorded in that DB.

I though of adding the `auditID` in response and use it later in the Filters, but the controller while making call to service layer of Customer doesn't pass response. Also this idea will need a lot of changes in all other entities too.

Any Idea on how this can be done.

Note: Tech Stack is `Java`, `Spring`, `Hibernate`.